# Check if URL exists within a function in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am a beginner with D3.js I am stuck with a problem for last few days. below is the code snippet

```
function zoomed() {
var tiles = tile
  .scale(zoom.scale())
  .translate(zoom.translate())
  ();

projection
  .scale(zoom.scale() / 2 / Math.PI)
  .translate(zoom.translate()); 

var image = layer
  .style(prefix + "transform", matrix3d(tiles.scale, tiles.translate))
.selectAll(".tile")
  .data(tiles, function(d) { return d; });


image.exit()
  .remove();

image.enter().append("img")
  .attr("class", "tile")
  .attr("src", function(d) {  return "http://111.118.179.198/Data/63699_1600x1200-wallpaper-cb1362414617.jpg_" + 8 + "_" + d[0] + "_" + d[1] + ".png"; })
  .style("left", function(d) {return (d[0] << 8) + "px"; })
  .style("top", function(d) { return (d[1] << 8) + "px"; });
}
```

my requirement is before I set the src attribute to img I need to check whether the url is an existing one, if it is a valid existing url then proper value will get set to src otherwise src will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

This would easier to do with jQuery:

```
var url = "some_url";
  $.ajax(url,
  {
     statusCode: {
       200: function() {
         image.attr("src," url);
       },
       404: function() {
         image.attr("src", otherURL);
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Lars,Thanks for your answer, but I am still not clear about this. I have added some more code,previous code was a part of the function "zoomed". I am not able to incorporate the solution you have prescribed. How should I proceed?

Comment: This check needs an AJAX call, so it would be asynchronous. That is, add the element first and set the `src` attribute later when the callback returns.

Comment: Hi Lars, This is how far i have been, http://jsfiddle.net/nilarya/gvf7V/3/. Can you please help me here.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/gvf7V/4/ -- this doesn't work because of security restrictions, but you can see what I mean.